# Where is @Html.MailTo in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mailto

I read on many forums suggesting to use @Html.MailTo to send emails using local client (i.e similar to "mailto:" in anchor.

But when I try doing that, I simply dont find "MailTo" option in intellisense... Am I missing something, or if its obsolete now, or if its a customer HtmlHelper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@Html.Mailto` is one of the Features of `ASP.NET MVC 3 Futures`. ASP.NET MVC 3 Futures includes a bunch of features which may become the part of ASP.NET MVC in future.

Inorder to use it you need to download it from [codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781)

You can check all the features in [Imran Baloch's Blog Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/07/26/using-the-features-of-asp-net-mvc-3-futures.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Html.DisplayFor` such as `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.emailAddress)` and it will produce an email link.

Comment: Unless the model property is marked up with a helper attribute e.g. `[DataType(DataTypes.EmailAddress)]`, you need to specify the EmailAddress DisplayTemplate explicitly e.g. `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.emailAddress, "EmailAddress")`

Comment: It should be DataType.EmailAddress instead of DataTypes.EmailAddress